# If we are allowing anonymous users to register inside our web site, how we can prevent hackers from occupying others' email address

Tags: architecture, asp.net-core, users, hacking, register

I am planning to start a new asp.net core MVC web application. One of the features we are having is that anonymous users can register inside our web application by entering their email addresses. then our system will send them a confirmation email, to activate their accounts.

Now by default the system will show error message, in-case a user try to register using existing email address, even if the existing email address was not confirmed. now this will pose a major problem in our system, is that hackers can use others' email addressees, and prevent them from registering inside our web application. Our web application is a CRM-like for real estate companies, and hackers can try to add as many email addresses has they want, they can get these email addresses from the companies' web sites such as `info@..`, `contact@...`, `admin@..` , etc.
So is there any problem if I do the following modifications:-

1. If the user did not confirm the email address in 1 hour, then the system will automatically remove his email address?
2. When I want to check if an email address is unique to check only the approved email addresses.

Comment: How much time does someone have to confirm their email address?

Comment: @RobertHarvey for your second comment, by defualt asp.net core will not have any restriction on this..so the user can confirm the email after couple of days, by defualt the asp.net core is open ,,, any restriction need to be implemented by us..

Comment: My suggestion would be to expire unconfirmed emails after an hour.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `My suggestion would be to expire unconfirmed emails after an hour.` ok sound valid

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if "hackers" try to fraudulently register info@ somecompany.com in an attempt to lock out somecompany, but the actual owner of info@ gets the confirmation email you send, then they're not really locked out of your site, are they? The reason this scenario rarely happens is that it doesn't have the effect that the hacker desires and that you're concerned about. Having said that, building in the pending email expiration is still an ok thing to do.

Comment: Actually the hack to be concerned about here isn't hacker A pretending to be new user B. It's hacker A pretending to be new users B to ZZZZZZ and getting you added to the email spammers black list so no one knows someone is pretending to be them.

Comment: @EricKing Yes your point is 100% valid.. but most of the times, if `info@...` receive such an email, they might ignore it.. and when they try to register later on (after 1 month or 1 years), they will get that their email address is already registered.. so i think i confirmed emails need to be removed from the system in a way or another.. + when checking for uniqueness only confirmed emails need to be checked ,, is this correct?

Comment: @candied_orange can you please explain your point in more details?

Comment: He's saying that you could potentially be the victim of a form of DOS attack.    You should study up on such things if you have the responsibility of building a secure system.

Comment: And to answer your point about checking for uniqueness: if you removed unconfirmed emails after an hour, you don't have to bother distinguishing between registered and unregistered emails.

Comment: A confirmation email system exposes a resource unsecured. It has to since it's how you build a secure relationship. That unsecured resource gives anyone the ability to make you send emails. Since you can't secure that with authentication you need to throttle it to reasonable levels to prevent getting blacklisted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes DOS attacks is been taken care of, i will add captcha on any form which anonymous users submit + if the same users from the same IP try to do successive  submissions,, they will be blocked temporarily.. but this will not prevent a hacker from registering let say 5 email addresses per day and for 3 months they can occupy 450 emails... etc...

Comment: @candied_orange so you are talking about blacklists inside users' email systems such as outlook, yahoo, etc.. is this correct? i think this need extra attention, but on so many scenarios where i register inside a forum or web site the confirmation email goes to Junk, and part of the message i get when submitting the registration form, is that **i should receive a confirmation email shortly and if not to check my junk folder**... seems this is a common issue.. is it?

Comment: @candied_orange So, building a soft DOS attack into the system to prevent the hard DOS of being blacklisted by email providers?

Comment: @testtest Any time you send out automated emails you risk getting blacklisted. If your domain name means something to you then you should take measures to protect it. Yes it's a common issue. One that even the pros are still struggling with to get right.

Comment: @candied_orange but i mean this type of problems can not get fixed... is this correct? i mean we can not stop sending confirmation emails to prevent our domain from being blacklisted?

Comment: @testtest well sure you can. There is nothing magical about having an email address. I have several. I didn't need an email address to get them. You are not uniquely identifying people by demanding a working email address. You are leveraging someone elses (the email provider) system of limiting consumption of a resource. The only other thing this ensures is that you have a way to communicate to an email address. Nothing ensures anyone is reading it one day from now.

Comment: @candied_orange so how i need to appraoch this ? most web applications works in this way >> you register using email address >> get confirmation email >> click on the confirmation link >>  get activated.. i am not sure if i am understanding things correctly?

Comment: @testtest yes that how. But I want you to understand the limits of what that really gets you. There are sites out there that freely give people email addresses that only last for minutes before someone else can use them. Same with phone numbers that receive SMS texts. That doesn't mean what you're doing is pointless. Just understand that what it provides is limited. All you are really doing is ramping up the effort it takes to consume your resource. You need to ensure proof of that effort to protect yourself from abuse.

Comment: Just a question, how can the user be annonymous if it's forced to inform an email?

Comment: @Laiv i mean before they actually get registered.. now our web application have a register form available for any public/anonymous user.. just as you can access any public web site..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of verifying the email address is to obtain proof that the owner of the email address and the user who registered are the same person. It therefore follows, that the logical thing to do if an email address remains unverified for a significant length of time, that the user who registered is not actually the owner of that account, or you have reason to doubt that it is the case.

> If the user did not confirm the email address in 1 hour, then the system will automatically remove his email address?

If your registration process is fully automated and quick, a there should be no problem with that. If your registration process is slow or involves manual intervention, 1 hour may not be enough time. But, if you have manual intervention in the registration process, then you don't need a waiting period if a human can spot a large number of bogus registrations and deal with them.

> When I want to check if an email address is unique to check only the approved email addresses.

In that case, it is possible for two users to start the registration process with the same email address. One of them could complete verification before the other one, so how do you handle the second user? You may say that "well, only one of them has the email address legitimately" but what if the same person tries to register two users by mistake? Or sends one registration, decides to change the username or something, so registers again, gets two emails, and picks the one for the username they didn't want? It sounds silly but users can be silly, especially non-technical users.

I would avoid having to handle those failure modes by saying whoever registers first gets to keep it, provided they have verified. If there's a 1 hour period where a legitimate user can't register with their real address, then it's really not that big of a deal, especially if you allow users to change the email addresses associated with their accounts.